# Giveaway command throws Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm try to make a giveaway command for my bot but it throws an error. I'm trying to fix this but I don't know what's wrong with it.

```js
var embedSent = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Giveaway Ended!")
  .setDescription(`React with :tada: to enter the giveaway!\nHosted By: **${message.author}**\nTime: **${time}**\nPrize: **${prize}**`)
  .setTimestamp(Date.now + ms(args[1]))
  .setColor(3447003)

channel.send(embed).then(newMessage => {
  newMessage.react('')
}).catch(e => {
  message.channel.send(`An error occurred while running the command You shouldnt ever receive an error like this Please contact <@390690088348024843> in this server  **${item}** : ` + "`" + e + "`")
  return;
})
setTimeout(async() => {
    try {
      const peopleReactedBot = embedSent.reactions.cache.get("").users.fetch();
      var peopleReacted = peopleReactedBot.array().filter(u => u.id !== client.user.id);
    } catch (e) {
      return message.channel.send(`An unknown error happened during th draw of the giveaway **${item}** : ` + "`" + e + "`")
    }
```

It throws this error:

`An unknown error happened during th draw of the giveaway test : TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined`

Comment: `embedSent.reactions` is undefined. We can't tell you any more than that with only the 1 line of code you posted...

Comment: so reactions  is undefined bc embedSent is defined

Comment: No, if `embedSent` was undefined then the message would be "_Cannot read property 'reactions' of undefined_". What is undefined is `reactions`.

Comment: How would i fix this

Comment: Again, since you only showed us the 1 line of code we cannot tell you anything more. What is `embedSent`? Where did it get a value? What is `reactions`? Where did it get a value? Etc... Maybe someone else will follow your code link and sort through everything, but I will not. If you condense all the required info into this question then maybe I can help.

Comment: i did press link

Comment: @lvar i cant bc it going to say it mostly code

Comment: @lvar done i tried

Comment: Thanks @Kofidave. Your `embedSent` seems to be an `MessageEmbed` element. This class doesn't seem to have a `reactions` property. See [the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed). You probably need to get the message itself instead of the `MessageEmbed`, though I have to admin that I'm not too familiar with Discord. Also I assume you meant to send `embedSent` instead of `embed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`embedSent` is just an [embed in a message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed), it's not the sent message you can react to. Once it's sent, the returned value (`newMessage`) is where you can get the reactions from. You used `newMessage.react` correctly, but you should also use `newMessage.reactions` and not `embedSent.reactions` as `embedSent` is still just an embed you can send in a message.

To access `newMessage` in your `setTimeout` you either need to move it inside the `.then()` method or you could `await` the message.

Also, `fetch()` returns a promise, so don't forget to use `await` before `users.fetch()` too. Check out the snippet below how you could organise your code:

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('Giveaway Ended!')
  .setDescription(
    `React with :tada: to enter the giveaway!\nHosted By: **${message.author}**\nTime: **${time}**\nPrize: **${prize}**`
  )
  .setTimestamp(Date.now + ms(args[1]))
  .setColor(3447003);

try {
  const sent = await message.channel.send(embed);
  sent.react('');

  setTimeout(async () => {
    try {
      const peopleReactedBot = await sent.reactions.cache
        .get('')
        .users.fetch();

      const peopleReacted = peopleReactedBot
        .array()
        .filter((u) => u.id !== client.user.id);
      console.log({ peopleReacted });
    } catch (e) {
      message.channel.send(
        `An unknown error happened during the draw of the giveaway **${item}**: \`${e}\``
      );
    }
  }, timeout);
} catch (e) {
  message.channel.send(
    `An error occurred while running the command You shouldn't ever receive an error like this Please contact <@390690088348024843> in this server  **${item}**: \`${e}\``
  );
}
```

You should probably look into the [reaction collector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector). It could work fine with a giveaway command. There is a [basic collector example](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors) on discordjs.guide.

Comment: I did not work 
 sent.react is not a function

Comment: plus same problem with cache

Comment: As I can't see more of your code, I can't really help you. The code above works for me, I've just tested it. Try to edit your question and add some more code, so I could check it.

Comment: ok i will just give you a link to full code

Comment: In your code, there is `message.react` instead of `sent.react`, and no `await` before `sent.reactions.cache`. Please, check my code again and try to fix yours based on this. As I said, my code works, I tested it with my bot.

Comment: here error``` TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined```